# NullReferenceException after turning ascx UserControl into reusable server control using Microsoft's tips

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, user-controls, c#-3.0, custom-server-controls

A supposedly [proven technique to turn UserControls of a website into reusable server controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479318.aspx) while retaining the ability to use declarative code gives me a `NullReferenceException` on any reference of any control that's declared inside the ASCX code.

When calling the ASCX from the same project, this problem does not occur.

The idea is that the on-demand compilation of the declarative code of the controls is done (precompiled website). After applying aspnet_merge, the awkwardly named assemblies receive normal names, however, if this first step isn't working... What I did, in short:

1. Create a website, add a usercontrol, add a Literal and set its text in the code-behind. Test it.
2. Compile to fixed named assembly, non-updatable
3. Take the output DLL, add them to another webite project and test them.

The last step gives me the null reference exception the minute I try to access any property of a declaratively initialized control from within that control (i.e., in the Page_Load in my case).

PS: Scott Guthrie [explains the same technique here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/28/423888.aspx).

Comment: Did you ever come across a solution to this issue?  I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: I did a lot of searching and found no solution to this problem. Looks like a real bug somewere deep in ASP.NET code which totally breaks the idea of using template controls :(